# Excel: Copying Selected Items From a Filter

Tags: excel

I have a filter in an Excel file (in pivot table), and I have selected quite a lot of items for filtering.

I need to make a reports and list all the seleted items from the filter. However, I do not want to write manually the name of every selected item.

Is there a way to simply copy the selected items in filter and paste them in a different place?

Answer (score 1):

The following VBA subroutine will export the selection criteria of the Autofilter of a given worksheet to a new Worksheet in the Workbook:

```vb
Public Sub ExportFilter(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
Dim hsFilter As Worksheet
    Dim rFilter As Range, rHeader As Range, rCell As Range, lFilter As Long, lMin As Long, lMax As Long, lStep As Long
    Dim bFilterOn As Boolean, lFilterOperator As Long, vFilterCriteria1 As Variant, vFilterCriteria2 As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not (ws.AutoFilterMode) Then Exit Sub
    Set rFilter = ws.AutoFilter.Range
    If rFilter Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set rHeader = rFilter.Rows(2)

    If hsFilter Is Nothing Then
        With ActiveSheet
            Set hsFilter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            'hsFilter.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            .Activate
        End With
    Else
         hsFilter.Rows.Delete
    End If

    For Each rCell In rHeader.Cells
        lFilter = 1 + rCell.Column - rHeader.Cells(1, 1).Column

        bFilterOn = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(lFilter).On
        hsFilter.Cells(1, lFilter).Value = bFilterOn

        If bFilterOn Then
            lFilterOperator = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(lFilter).Operator
            hsFilter.Cells(2, lFilter).Value = lFilterOperator

            If lFilterOperator = xlFilterValues Then '7
                vFilterCriteria1 = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(lFilter).Criteria1
                Set vFilterCriteria2 = Nothing
                lMin = LBound(vFilterCriteria1)
                lMax = UBound(vFilterCriteria1)
                For lStep = lMin To lMax
                    hsFilter.Cells(3 + lStep, lFilter).NumberFormat = "@"
                    vFilterCriteria2 = vFilterCriteria1(lStep)
                    If Len(CStr(vFilterCriteria2)) > 1 And Left(CStr(vFilterCriteria2), 1) = "=" Then
                        vFilterCriteria2 = Mid(vFilterCriteria2, 2, Len(vFilterCriteria2) - 1)
                    End If
                    hsFilter.Cells(3 + lStep - lMin, lFilter).Value = vFilterCriteria2
                Next lStep
            ElseIf (lFilterOperator = 0) Or (lFilterOperator = xlTop10Items) Or (lFilterOperator = xlTop10Percent) Or (lFilterOperator = xlFilterDynamic) Then  'One Filter
                vFilterCriteria1 = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(lFilter).Criteria1
                Set vFilterCriteria2 = Nothing
                hsFilter.Cells(3, lFilter).NumberFormat = "@"
                If Len(CStr(vFilterCriteria1)) > 1 And Left(CStr(vFilterCriteria1), 1) = "=" Then
                    vFilterCriteria1 = Mid(vFilterCriteria1, 2, Len(vFilterCriteria1) - 1)
                End If
                hsFilter.Cells(3, lFilter).Value = vFilterCriteria1
            Else
                vFilterCriteria1 = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(lFilter).Criteria1
                vFilterCriteria2 = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(lFilter).Criteria2
                hsFilter.Cells(3, lFilter).NumberFormat = "@"
                If Len(CStr(vFilterCriteria1)) > 1 And Left(CStr(vFilterCriteria1), 1) = "=" Then
                    vFilterCriteria1 = Mid(vFilterCriteria1, 2, Len(vFilterCriteria1) - 1)
                End If
                hsFilter.Cells(3, lFilter).Value = vFilterCriteria1
                hsFilter.Cells(4, lFilter).NumberFormat = "@"
                If Len(CStr(vFilterCriteria2)) > 1 And Left(CStr(vFilterCriteria2), 1) = "=" Then
                    vFilterCriteria2 = Mid(vFilterCriteria2, 2, Len(vFilterCriteria2) - 1)
                End If
                hsFilter.Cells(4, lFilter).Value = vFilterCriteria2
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    Set rFilter = Nothing
    Set rHeader = Nothing
    Set vFilterCriteria1 = Nothing
    Set vFilterCriteria2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: any way to do it without a VBA script?
if not, can you pls shortly describe how I can run/insert/use this script?

Comment: @Adam Press `Alt` + `F11` to open VBA, Insert a Module, and paste that code in.  Then press `Ctrl` + `G` to open the immediate window, and call the function on your worksheet (e.g. if your worksheet is called "My Filtered Sheet" then type `ExportFilter ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My Filtered Sheet")` and press `Enter`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the advanced filter by criteria and use the Copy to option.
Data - Advanced (on the sort & filter section)

Here is how https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b?NS=EXCEL&Version=90&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL900&HelpId=21102&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US